# How do I prove this expression?

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_3(2) \times \log_4(3) \times \log_5(4) \times \cdots \times \log_{16}(15) = \frac{1}{4}$$

> I have tried to simplify all the arguments but I could not work it out. Do I have to reduce the terms to a common base? Or form an equation? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify some more.  Logarithms are functions, yet you have no inputs.  Furthermore, as the way your problem is currently stated, there is no natural progression for the ellipsis to make sense for.

Comment: You can use $\log_{b}x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$

Comment: @user84413 and multiplication of natural logarithms is exponentiation...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I was using that the left side simplifies to $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln16}=\frac{\ln 2}{4\ln 2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @user84413 but how can you get that? You have to factor in all the expontents...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck This is the same method used by Claude Leibovici in his answer; all the logs cancel except $\ln 2$ and $\ln 16$ when you write out the product.

Comment: @user84413 i did not see that they were sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering $$P_n=\prod_{i=2}^n \log_{i+1}(i)$$ Using natural logarithms, this write $$P_n=\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{\log(i)}{\log(i+1)}$$ and you see that the $(p-1)^{th}$ term in denominator is the same as the $p^{th}$ term in numerator. So, most terms disappear and making all the simplifications, you should get $$P_n=\frac{\log (2)}{\log (n+1)}$$ So, to get a rational number, it is required that $n+1=2^k$ and, if this is the case, then $$P_n=\frac 1k$$

Similarly, if you have $$Q_n=\prod_{i=2}^n \log_{i}(i+1)=\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{\log(i+1)}{\log(i)}=\frac{\log (n+1)}{\log (2)}$$ and, if $n+1=2^k$, $Q_n=k$.